# Cant connect to rails docker container on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

Im having trouble accessing my containerized rails app from my local machine. I'm following [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) quickstart guide as a template and made some tweaks to the paths for my gemfile and gemfile.lock. The quickstart guide moves on to docker-compose, but I want to try accessing the app without it first to get familiar with these processes before moving on.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile ./Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock ./Gemfile.lock
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000:3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

and this is the entrypoint file:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid

# Then exec the container's main process (what's set as CMD in the Dockerfile).
exec "$@"
```

I am able to successfully build and run the image, but when I try to access 0.0.0.0:3000 I get a cant connect error. [image]

I also attached a screenshot of my app directory structure, the Dockerfile and entrypoint are at the root.

One thing that seems strange is when I try to run the logs for the container I dont get any output, but when I shut the container down I see the startup logs. Not sure why that is.

I am running docker desktop 2.1.0.3. Any thoughts/help are very appreciated.

Comment: How are you running the container?

Comment: Try command docker inspect to investigate your container IP. Then, try accessing this IP directly on port 3000.

Comment: @DavidMaze im using the cli, docker run image

Comment: @KrzysztofWitczak Ive tried that and it gets hung up and timesout

Comment: If you’re just using `docker run imagename`, it won’t be accessible anywhere unless you add a `-p` option.  The container-private IP addresses are unreachable in a variety of common situations and I wouldn’t recommend trying to look them up.

Comment: @DavidMaze that worked great, thanks. Curious, why does the port need to be set in the docker run command even though we expose 3000 to the host in the dockerfile? Maybe thats too broad a q. Also if you want to submit an answer Ill accept it

Answer (score 2):

use just `EXPOSE 3000` in dockerfile. 
run container `ror` with mapping port to localhost from your new docker image `<image>`

```
docker run -d --name ror -p 3000:3000 <image>
```

now you should be able to access `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of mine that works:

1. The usual dockerfile, nothing special here.
2. Then, in docker-compose.yml, add environment variable, or place in .env file, the DATABASE_URL (important bit is using the host.docker.internal instead of localhost
3. Then in your database.yml, specify the url with the ENV key

Then start the container by running docker-compose up

#Dockerfile

```html
FROM ruby:3.0.5-alpine


RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
      bash \
      build-base \
      tzdata \
      postgresql-dev \
      yarn \
      git \
      curl \
      wget \
      gcompat

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
WORKDIR /app

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash 
RUN gem install bundler:2.4.3
RUN bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
RUN bundle install

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "--pid=/tmp/server.pid"]
```

#docker-compose.yml

```html
  version: "3.9"
  services:
    app:
      image: your_app_name
      volumes:
        - /app
      env_file:
        - .env
      environment:
        - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres@host.docker.internal:5432/<your_db_name>
      ports:
      - "3000:3000"

    webpack_dev_server:
      build: .
      command: bin/webpack-dev-server
      ports:
        - "3035:3035"
      volumes:
        - /app
      env_file:
        - .env
      environment:
        - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0

    redis:
      image: redis
```

#database.yml

```html
development:
  <<: *default
  database: giglifepro_development
  url: <%= ENV.fetch('DATABASE_URL') %>
```